# Is there a way to center my social media icons in media query using Flexbox?

Tags: html, css, responsive, footer

I'm having trouble understanding how to center my social media icons in mobile. How do I do so?

I'm supposed to make social media icons responsive. I tried using Flexbox for my footer. I used `text-align: right` or `align-items: right`.

I created media queries to override it like `text-align: center` or `align-items: center`. However, when I was testing it out in responsive mode via Firefox Developer Edition, it would not budge.

**Update** I changed it to Font Awesome icons and styled it. I'm still not able to make my icons center under media query.

**HTML**

```
<footer class="main-footer">
  <div class="footer-content">
    <ul class="contact-links">
      <li><i class="fab fa-github" alt="GitHub"></i></li>
      <li><i class="fab fa-linkedin" alt="LinkedIn></i></li>
      <li><i class="fab fa-twitter-square" alt="Twitter"></i></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</footer>
```

**CSS**

```
/*** index.html footer ***/
.main-footer{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: right;
}

/*** index.html footer ***/

footer{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: right;
  text-align: right;
}

.main-footer > .footer-content {
    position:relative;
}

/*** index.html - Footer - Social Media Contact Icons/Links ***/

ul.contact-links .fab {
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size:24px;
  color: #CC3366;
}

ul.contact-links {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline-block;
}

ul.contact-links li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 5px;
}

/* index.html Main Footer Media Queries */

@media (max-width: 480px) {
footer{
  display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
  }
}
```

What am I missing? Is there anything else I should add?

Comment: Is there any reason you arent using something like font awesome to use icons? will make styling them much easier, and code examples you give far easier for us to help you with

Comment: Also suggest font icons, makes things like `text-align: center` make this a breeze

Comment: Initially, it was because I wanted to customize the colors of the icons. Is it better to use font awesome icons?

Comment: @Chizzele font-awesome library for 3 icons would add unnecessary load, but is a good option, if you are gonna make use a lot of iconography in the project.

Comment: Thanks, I updated them into font awesome icons. Still not able to center them when I test it in responsive design mode in Firefox Developer Edition.

Comment: can you share a snippet?

Comment: Here's a CodePen: https://codepen.io/formyjourney/pen/xevJQv

Comment: the issue is *specificity* of `.footer-main` than just `footer` when the *media query* kicks in - use `.foooter-main` instead of `footer` in the *media query*: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QPeZbL

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using justify-content: center

Comment: Here is a resource to help understand flexbox. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Aligning_Items_in_a_Flex_Container

Answer (score 0):

Wrong selectors in your CSS might be your problem.
You have `.footer` in your CSS but you have it in HTML. You might mean just `footer`

In flexbox, if you want to center something, You just add a `display: flex` in the wrapper element. Then also apply

```css
align-items: center;
```

to center its content vertically

```css
justify-content: center;
```

to center its content horizontally